# Include directives in gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

We have a bunch of repositories, and we'd like to manage our gitignore files from a single place.

Is is possible to define "includes", possibly over HTTP(S) so that we can just place that stanza in the gitignore file, and then we can make changes in a single place?

I know about the global gitignore files, but that needs to be modified by every developer, which is not really an option.

Thanks,

Comment: Maintain the pre-receive hook in the remote repository. If any file or folder that should have been ignored is tracked in a commit, then reject the push and notify the user in the error log to update his own gitignore and amend the commit.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not supported with VSTS

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: check out https://github.com/SlideWave/gitignore-include

```
## <include href="https://github.com/github/gitignore/raw/main/Global/Images.gitignore">
# Anything in here will be replaced and updated when you want it to be.
## </include>

## <include module="modulename">
# Supports node modules!
## </include>

## <include file="./other.example">
# Local files!
## </include>

# Anything not between the tags is ignored.
whatever/else
```

It does require an extra processing step however as it's tool that helps generate the ignore file.